# If $v_1,v_2$ are two non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$, span$\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a plane through the origin

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a true/false question

If $v_1,v_2$ are two non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$, span$\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a plane through the origin

This is true since it falls under the geometric definiton of a span.

Any other opinions on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false, and you have a counter-example whenever $v_1,v_2$ are linearly dependent. For instance, if $v_1=e_1$ and $v_2=2e_1$, then their span is just $span(e_1)$, a line through the origin.

Comment: Cool another thing is that I was thinking: is the span([0,0,0]) a line through the origin?

Comment: No, the span of the zero-vector is precisely the zero-vector itself. This is the only vector whose span is not a line.